# How to manage a daemonizing subprocess in python

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess, posix

I'm trying to start and manage (be able to terminate and restart in case that it fails for any reason) a process in python using the subprocess module.

I'm opening each process in a different thread and than call wait on them. The problem is that the processes main process exits after forking and daemonizing so the wait returns (exits with exit code 0) immediately even though the processes actually continue. The processes creates a pid_file that contain the pid of the new daemon process.

```
while True:
    self.popen = subprocess.Popen(command)

    self.popen.wait()

    if self.popen.returncode == 0:
        break
```

How can I monitor and wait the forked processes?

Comment: What is the `command` here? What are you trying to do specifically? Are you certain that using a Python subprocess is the right solution?

Comment: I think that you should describe exactly what you are trying to obtain instead of trying to find a fix for your current implementation attempt. My impression is that you are trying to start a service from python instead of making a python service.

Comment: I have several services written in C that needs to be started and managed. I'm trying to write some kind of process manager (I can't use a generic one like systemd/supervisord) that will start the services and restart them if they fail.

Comment: why can't you use the standard tools provided by `systemd` (e.g., `systemctl restart docker`) or manage the daemons using `supervisord` API?

Comment: We had multiple problems with systemd (also tried supervisord) and because of a specific need we have we decided to write a specific basic one for ourselves.

Comment: @ItayWeiss Why can't you set up the services that you're starting to not daemonize? Even if they need to daemonize some of the time, it's relatively standard practice to have an option to turn off daemonization.

Comment: @CelSkeggs They do have an option to turn off daemonization but I need them to daemonize in this case.

Comment: @ItayWeiss Why do you need to daemonize in this case?